# HTML visual not rendering properly

Tags: javascript, html, css

Please view the code here.. [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wcmHu/34/). There is a peculiar problem that a blue colored underscore is appearing right after the first image. Why is this happening? Note that just removing the href makes it disappear. Very peculiar problem. What should be done?

HTML:

```
<body>
    <div id="top-bar"> 
        <a target="_blank" href="https://twitter.com/x">
            <img class="twitter" src="images/twitter.png">
        </a>
        <a target="_blank">
            <img class="twitter" src="images/twitter.png">
        </a>
        <a target="_blank" href="https://www.facebook.com/x">
            <img id="fb" src="images/fb.png"
                 onmouseover="this.src='images/fb-hover.png'"
                 onmouseout="this.src='images/fb.png'">
        </a>

    </div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
#top-bar {
    height: 50px;
    min-height: 50px;
    max-height: 50px;
    background-color: #166330;
}
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background-image: url(images/bg.png);
    background-size: 100%;
    color: white;
}
.twitter {
    margin-left: 30px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    min-height: 30px;
    min-width: 30px;
    max-height: 30px;
    max-width: 30px;
}
#fb {
    min-height: 30px;
    min-width: 30px;
    max-height: 30px;
    max-width: 30px;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two ways.

1] Remove all the `white spaces` between `<a>` `<img/>` and `</a>` tags.

2] Add `text-decoration:none;` to the `<a>` elements.

Answer (score 1):

That's a blank inside your `a` tag.

If you write it without blanks like this, no "underscore" appears. E.g. something like:

```
<a target="_blank" href="https://twitter.com/x"><img class="twitter" 
    src="images/twitter.png"></a>
```

So the "underscore" is actually a link with a blank text and the browser displays links with an underscore, even if the text is just a white-space.

Comment: Then, why is the `#fb` being rendered properly?

Answer (score 0):

simple.. just use this

```
a{
  text-decoration:none;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

user  style="text-decoration:none" in tag A

```
<a  style="text-decoration:none" href=....
```